# datatable search option and paging not displaying in the mvc view

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatable

i have one data table . I'm fetching data from dataset and populating into the datatable. I'm referring https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html.i have added references of data table and jquery still im facing issues to view the data table features. im not able to see the search box and paging option.

view

```
@using System.Data
@model DataSet
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="    https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
    <title>Index</title>
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Use case</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>SMS</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@row["updtd_date"]</td>
                <td>@row["usecase"]</td>
                <td>@row["id"]</td>
                <td>@row["sms"]</td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>


@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        });
</script>
    }
```

Comment: you are referring a css file in your Script reference.

Comment: Please correct the reference to `datatable` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Add reference to `datatables` script.

2- Add `thead` and `tbody` to your table.

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
 <thead>
    <tr>    
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Use case</th>
     <th>Id</th>
     <th>SMS</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
   {
    <tr>
     <td>@row["updtd_date"]</td>
      <td>@row["usecase"]</td>
      <td>@row["id"]</td>
      <td>@row["sms"]</td>
     </tr>
   }
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your Script reference to:

```
<script src="    https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `datatables` also need `thead` and `tbody`.